# How do I select a date in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a column with DATA_TYPE = DATE. When I query the table, an example of data from that column is

```
28-APR-08
```

So I'm trying to query it like so:

```
select * from mytable where mydatecolumn = '28-APR-08'
```

This returns nothing. I also tried this:

```
select * from mytable where mydatecolumn = TO_DATE('2008/04/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

This also returns nothing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You see the value '28-APR-08' because of your regional settings (google NLS_DATE_FORMAT for more info). By default, only the date is shown, not the time portion. Check the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE just_a_date(mydate DATE);
Table JUST_A_DATE created.
INSERT INTO just_a_date(mydate) VALUES (SYSDATE);
1 row inserted.
SELECT * FROM just_a_date;
27-SEP-2019
SELECT * FROM just_a_date WHERE mydate = '27-SEP-19';
no rows selected
```

That is what you are seeing. The Oracle DATE datatype stores both DATE and TIME up to the second. Lets take a closer look at the data in the table just_a_date by using a format mask.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(mydate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  FROM just_a_date;
27-SEP-2019 14:50:51
```

There you go. There is a time portion to it. If you query for `mydate = '27-SEP-19'` then Oracle will implicitely convert that to `27-SEP-2019 00:00:00` and you will get no rows. You will get the rows if you specify the time portion up to the second.

```
SELECT * FROM just_a_date WHERE mydate = TO_DATE('27-SEP-2019 14:50:51','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
27-SEP-2019
```

Or ... if you don't care about the time portion, you can use the TRUNC function. That will remove the time portion from the DATE column.

```
SELECT * FROM just_a_date WHERE TRUNC(mydate)  = TO_DATE('27-SEP-2019','DD-MON-YYYY');
27-SEP-2019
```

Comment: Good answer, in order to be even better you should use like `TO_DATE('27-SEP-2019','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')` in order to be independent from current user session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`

Answer (score 0):

> The RR datetime format element is similar to the YY datetime format
>   element, but it provides additional flexibility for storing date
>   values in other centuries. The RR datetime format element lets you
>   store 20th century dates in the 21st century by specifying only the
>   last two digits of the year.

So,use `'DD-MON-RR'` as date format for your case :

```
select * from mytable where mydatecolumn = to_date('28-APR-08','DD-MON-RR')
```

Answer (score 0):

Barbaros has given the perfect solution but I think we can add much more  description.

Whenever two digit years are used, following is the behaviour of `rr` and `yy`:

- **rr**:

50-99 are interpreted as 1950-1999, i.e. **previous century dates**,
and dates ending in 00-49 are interpreted as 2000-2049, i.e. **current century dates**.

- **yy:**

In case of yy, there is no such descrimination and it stores 2000 to 2099 for 00-99 i.e. **only current century dates**.

Few examples:

```
To_date('20-07-89', 'dd-mm-yy') --> 20 july, 2089
To_date('20-07-89', 'dd-mm-rr') --> 20 july, 1989

To_date('20-07-19', 'dd-mm-yy') --> 20 july, 2019
To_date('20-07-19', 'dd-mm-rr') --> 20 july, 2019
```

Cheers!!